# Using Curl to decode and echo a RESTful API response

Tags: php, json, curl, restful-url

I am trying to simply take and display the data from "Last" from this API: 
 https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc

Here is what I have so far, however it is not returning anything.  I am not an experienced developer, and pieced this code from a few different sources.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

$service_url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);

echo $decoded->Last;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. But you have to check the JSON response more proper. If you want to get "Last" you first have to get result.

This is the JSON decoded Response from your code:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["message"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["result"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["Bid"]=>
    float(3760)
    ["Ask"]=>
    float(3765)
    ["Last"]=>
    float(3765)
  }
}
```

So, you would have to echo "$decoded->result->Last"

Answer (score 0):

`$decoded` return standard object so you cant directly print using echo .if you print decoded variable then

```
<?php
$service_url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($decoded);

 ?>
```

**Result:**

```
 stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => 
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Bid] => 3741.5957385
            [Ask] => 3745
            [Last] => 3745
        )

)
```

so you can access

```
echo $decoded->success; //return 1
echo $decoded->result->Bid; //3741
```